# Command 'ZkStartPreservingDatastore' failed for service 'zookeeper1'

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, apache-zookeeper

I need your help.I have a question with hadoop clustors starting.the error :
the error :Command 'ZkStartPreservingDatastore' failed for service 'zookeeper1'

please help me ,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I've encountered the same issue on our production CDH4 cluster. I've tried to restart the service manually, and what I've noticed in the logs was the following error message:

[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@193] - Too many connections from /10.0.2.133 - max is 50

So, I've edited **/etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg** and changed the maxClientCnxns to 500. After that I've manged to restart the zookeeper, and cluster came back.